# Background color covers only a half of the drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation. In DrawerContent I've added all needed things to make drawer's background green while it covers only a half of the drawer. Here is the code and image of the drawer.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gy55.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { View, ScrollView,Button,Text,StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';

const  DrawerContent = (props) => (

  <View style={style.container}>

    <DrawerItems {...props} />

  </View>

);

const style = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {

  flex:1

  height: null,

    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
  },
});

export default DrawerContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with the `DrawerContent` object. You should try giving that object the style that you want...

You are creating an object `DrawerContent` with the object `View` inside of it and giving it the style. In this case the `View` object might be smaller than the `DrawerContent` object...

Comment: I took most of this code from react-navigation documentation so there was inside View tags. Have you seen the image attached above?